# Android webview example doesn't work (R.layout.show_web_view);

Tags: android, layout, webview

I'm starting to learn how to develop an Android webview app.
When searching for tutorials, I found [this](http://androidexample.com/Show_Loader_To_Open_Url_In_WebView__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=125&aaid=145) example.

Now that code should work perfectly but I have a small issue with the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);
```

The error for the last line: *show_web_view cannot be resolved or is not a field.*

What should I do to make that error disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `show_web_view.xml` in your `res/layout` folder. If you have it but still getting this error, post the `show_web_view.xml` code.